# Spring CXF Webservice doesn't get deployed correctly

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wsdl, cxf

this is the situation: we have a Spring-MVC application that should now provide a contract-first SOAP webservice. After looking at a CXF example (wsdl_first), I finally managed to get this far:

I generated the skeleton classes and also implemented the service interface.

Tomcat 7 seems to deploy something:

```
12 Jan 2014 19:32:08,386  INFO org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean:411 - Creating Service {urn:webservice.x.com:wsdl}IdmAdapterService from WSDL: classpath:IdmAdapterService.wsdl
```

I created a second servlet which should handle the webservice calls. WEB-INF/web.xml contains:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml contains:

```
<jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="urn:webservice.x.com:wsdl"
    id="idmAdapterImpl" address="/services/IdmAdapterService"
    serviceName="tns:IdmAdapterService" endpointName="tns:IdmAdapterSoapPort"
    implementor="de.y.idm.IdmAdapterImpl"
    />
```

src/main/resources/cxf.xml contains:

```
<jaxws:endpoint name="{urn:webservice.x.com:wsdl}:IdmAdapterSoapPort"
    wsdlLocation="IdmAdapterService.wsdl">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

src/main/resources/server-applicationContext.xml contains:

```
<!-- HTTP Endpoint -->
<jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="urn:webservice.x.com:wsdl"
    id="idmAdapterImpl"
            address="/services/IdmAdapterService"
    serviceName="tns:IdmAdapterService"
            endpointName="tns:IdmAdapterSoapPort"
    implementor="de.y.idm.IdmAdapterImpl">
    <jaxws:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

When I call the URL

```
 http://localhost:8080/application/services/IdmAdaptorService?wsdl
```

I always end up with

```
 No service was found.
```

and on the console

```
12 Jan 2014 19:51:53,731 DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:136 - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
12 Jan 2014 19:51:53,732 DEBUG org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy:205 - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/services/idmadapterservice'; to: '/services/idmadapterservice'
12 Jan 2014 19:51:53,732 DEBUG org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy:212 - Candidate is: '/services/idmadapterservice'; pattern is /services/**; matched=true
12 Jan 2014 19:51:53,733 DEBUG org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy:165 -  has an empty filter list
12 Jan 2014 19:51:53,733  WARN org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController:175 - Can't find the the request for http://localhost:8080/application/services/IdmAdapterService's Observer 
12 Jan 2014 19:51:53,734 DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:154 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
12 Jan 2014 19:51:53,734 DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils:338 - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

What am I missing, what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `/services/IdmAdapterService` in `server-applicationContext.xml` is relative to the servlet-mapping of `CXFServlet` which is `/services/*`. So your actual path of the service should be:

`http://localhost:8080/application/services/services/IdmAdapterService`

Comment: Your comment lead me into the right direction. The service was deployed under the URL you've posted. I changed all `/services/IdmAdapterService` to `/IdmAdapterService` and I readched it. Thank you.